# MYSQLI / PHP: num_rows returns nothing/null

Tags: php, mysqli, null, return-value, mysql-num-rows

*I´ve read many topics with the same problem, but neither of any solved my problem*.
I´ve got following code:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('...');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Connect Error');
}
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
$success = $connection->query("INSERT INTO hilde_entrys (Comment, Refer_ID, Account_Adress) VALUES ('".$_POST["comment"]."','".$GET["id"]."','".$userData["user_address"]."')");
$success->store_result(); //I did this as it helped some people - it didn´t help me :(
$rows = $success->num_rows;
while($row = $success->fetch_row()) { //This whole while-loop helped some other guy on stackoverflow - not me
    $rows = $success->num_rows; //Incrementing by 1 each time
} 
$rows = $success->num_rows; // Finally the total count 

if ($rows > 0) { //What I actually intended to do with the num_rows...
    $success->free();
    $success->close();
    $connection->close();
} else {
    $success->free();
    $success->close();
    $connection->close();
    die("Query failed.");
}
```

Somehow, even though I tried everything possible, it just won´t return anything expected. (Yes, the query and everything else works. I tried it.). What is wrong?
Thank you for all your answers in advance,
VicStudio

Oh, btw: Even when i remove `$success->free();` it doesn´t change anything with `num_rows`....

**EDIT**: After you guys told me that `INSERT` won´t return any rows, how can i then check if the query succeeded?

**ONE MORE EDIT**: First, someone told me to use affected_rows instead of num_rows, which I can todally understand. Somehow, it still didn´t work, so one of you asked me to activate error reporting in my php-script, and I now got following **two** error messages (one notice and one fatal-error):
*Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in (my webpage) on line XX*
*Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in (my webpage) on line XX*
The notice refers to the line `$rows = $success->affected_rows;` (I replaced `$rows = $success->num_rows` with this). (I commented the while-loop away).
The second error, causing the screen to go blank, is referring to `$success->close();`, the one in the else-clause. This means
a) it doesn´t detect THAT something was changed and
b) that it has a problem with me closing the query.
Could somebody explain to me why? I checked my database and the INSERT-query succeeded, therefore it should have gone in the if, not in the else. And why doesn´t it want me closing the query? I assume both of these errors have something todo with eachother. Thanks in advance, guys. Sorry for the long time in between my new post, but it takes time figuring stuff out and especially writing it down.

Comment: An INSERT will not produce any rows for you to fetch. !!!!!!!

Comment: You should read up on sql injection...

Comment: Quote: _num_rows - Returns the number of rows in the result set._ You got no result set

Comment: @jeroen, I know this is pretty unsecure, but it is (until now) only an unstable developer version. Therefore, I will add the security part later on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That´s concludable, but why don´t i get one? I just did a query and want to check if it succeeded...

Comment: It's not just about security, it's about valid sql and quotes in the data will break yours. And security should never come later on.

Comment: [Take a dip in the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) Come on in the water is lovely

Comment: @jeroen Wow, ok! How can I get quotes working?

Comment: Also, if the INSERT query failed `$success` will be FALSE

Comment: You should read up on sql injection...

Comment: @jeroen You can lead a horse to water, but you cannot make it _think_

Comment: @jeroen Edited my post. Read it.

Comment: I read it, and gave an answer as it was a bit long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `mysqli_query()` running an INSERT query only returned either TRUE or FALSE then your `$success` will never be a `mysqli_result` object as it would in a SELECT Query.

Therefore your test for `affected_rows` should use the connection object like this. In fact the `affected_rows` property only even exists on the mysqli_object.

```
$connection->affected_rows;
```

So

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('...');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Connect Error');
}
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
$success = $connection->query("AN INSERT QUERY");

$rows = $connection->affected_rows;
```

> The PHP manual aint great in this area I admit, [but it does state this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

This also explains why

```
$success->free();
$success->close();
```

dont work as `$success` is not an object.

And also why

```
$success->store_result();
```

does not work. `$success` is not an object and there are no results to store.

Comment: You have solved the problem a)/notice, but there still is the fatal error saying that close() is trying to call a non-object in line 16 of the code snippet (it now took the correct claue, but still seems to have a problem with the close()-call...)

Comment: Read all the answer, may need a page refresh

Comment: EDIT: Now that i saw your new edit, i just tried it again and...IT WORKS! Thank you so much for all your help! Also thanks to Dragin, bringing me near tot he goal and to jeroen, showing me that security actually is a thing.

Answer (score 2):

For insertion you should use affected_rows `$rows = $success->affected_rows;`
[PHP affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Read about num_rows here [PHP num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Can't test at the moment  if that could be the case but did you try removing `$success->store_result()`?